How does Mario Party Advance use my silliest secret?
At the start of Mario Party Advance, the game asks me what my silliest secret is. How does this secret get used? Is there any way for someone to see what I wrote for my secret later on?


According to Reddit:

These are actually used in the multiplayer mode called “secret battle,” where you play minigames and the winner gets to see the other’s secret.

You can change your secret by going to the Passport menu and selecting Revise secret.

